design strategy of a pulse delay line between two components
There are two components 74ABT04D Hex inverter and UCC5304DWVR gate driver.
74ABT04D Hex inverter is the signal genrator UCC5304DWVR is the reciever of the delayed signal.
I know that my delay line has to be matched.Given the datasheet below what source and load I need to put for my delay line?
THanks.
https://www.mouser.co.il/datasheet/2/916/74ABT04-1541721.pdf
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc5304.pdf?ts=1715329802200&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.co.il%252F

What delay line are you referring to and where does it go in your circuit?

Hello Andy the hex invertor creates a square wave pulse , i want to delay it using LC ladder type circuit so it will reach UCC5304DWVR  input after some time.However i am not sure what source and load to use by the datasheets of the components when i design this LC ladder in LTSPICE.

A single section of LC delay line needs to be terminated in a resistor of value \$\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$: -

The one above is for 50 Ω i.e. \$\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$ = 50 Ω.
It can also be proven that for a decent range of frequencies (from DC up to a high frequency point), the input impedance will also be \$\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$. The point where it starts to unravel is about one-tenth of the resonant frequency formed by L and C. In the example above, that will be one-tenth of 31.8 MHz.
This means that if you want a decent delay line, you choose the resonant frequency to be about ten times higher than your maximum frequency (including relevant square wave harmonics).
How much delay comes from a single L and C? If I plot the phase response of the output from low frequencies up to (say) 1 MHz I get this: -

In other words, the phase increases linearly with frequency and, this equals a constant time delay. In the example above it 5 ns (\$\sqrt{L\cdot C}\$). At around one tenth of the resonant frequency (around 3.18 MHz) it starts to be a little non-linear in delay so, be aware of what values to pick.
And, of course, the LC section has the same input and output impedance so, multiple sections can be cascaded with a single terminator right at the end of the final section.
Images and some text taken from an answer I gave on Codidact

However I am not sure what source and load to use by the datasheets of the components when I design this LC ladder in LTSPICE.

You have options. Either terminate in a value as per the formula above or use a series terminator in the source of the same value (taking into account that your driving source my be circa 15 Ω. Series source termination example: -

The theoretical delay should be 20 ns but, it's more like 21 ns due to the higher-than-anticipated BW of the signal input (100 ns rise and fall times).

Hello Andy ,In the datasheet of ucc5304 section 9.1.1 they say not to input delay lines  :-) I still want to try.Is there a clue in the datasheet whereis says what in the input impedance of the input to ucc5304?
https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc5304.pdf?ts=1715329802200&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.co.il%252F

It looks like a CMOS input with TTL voltage levels and uses a Schmitt trigger format as per the diagram on page 14 and section 8.3.2. There is no section numbered 9.1.1.

Hello Andy, from section 8.3.2  shown below and what you said it seems that my load is open circuit (infinite load) but my LC has caracteristic impedance  so how can i match the LC section to the "LOAD" in such case?
Thanks.
ternal pull-down resistor forces the
pin low. This resistance is typically 200 kΩ (see Functional Block Diagram).

@rocko445 look at my last paragraph in my answer and try simulating with a source series termination.

Hello Andy, to tell truth this is the first time i heard of this idia :-) i googled it and saw connecting a transmission line in series I need to use lumped elemented not transmission lines..could you give me an example of series termination which could deal with  infinite load(100Kohm) when the pulse could go into the UCC5304 device with no reflections? Thanks

Why don't you set up a simulation using L and C in the same ratio I have them and use an ideal square wave to drive the line of cascaded stages via a 50 ohm resistor. That would help you I'm sure but, if still confused, why not raise a new post and open it to the floor.

Hello Andy, In your simulation the load is 50Ohm. my UCC5304 input impedance is 200K :-) so its a big difference .a series termination is like doing a quarter wave transformer? Thanks.

No, @rocko445 series source termination is a valid method of termination and doesn't just apply to quarter wave transmission lines. It's used in digital circuits in many places. The load end is open circuit or, high impedance.

Hello Andy , could you please do some example i could understand the logic of this method? Thanks.

Hello Andy, Another question regading your example: How did you transform the phase slope into the time delay the square wave will get?
Thanks.

At 1 MHz, the phase shift is 1.8 degrees or, 1.8/360 of the 1 MHz period @rocko445

Hello  ,by the definition of group delay group-delay=1.8degree/1MHz=1.8Mega degrees*seconds.
so if I put a pulse threw it, how do I know the amount of time my pulse will be shifted , because the units are degrees*time

No, @rocko445 1.8/360 is unitless. $\sqrt{LC}$ is another way of calculating the time delay. The link in my answer shows why.

Hello Andy , so my LC has 38Mhz bandwidth. Suppose i want to enter a pulse with rise/fall time of 100ns.
Which means the BW of the pulse is 3.5Mhz.
I have simulated the pulse below and i got a delay of 5ns.
Given this example
What is the mathematical calculation to get this 5ns delay from the group delay of group-delay=1.8degree/1MHz

$\sqrt{LC}$ as I said in my previous comment and my answer.

Hello Andy,Yes i understand its working as shown in the link simulation. could you please make a simulation on how to handle open circuit load instead of 50Ohm?
So i could learn from it?
Thanks.
https://ibb.co/K76xCfP

@rocko445 I think you are capable of this yourself after all, you've just linked me to an image of one you made earlier that looks like it produces a reasonable delay (20 ns by the looks of it). Just move the 50 ohm from the load and put it in series with the source and link me the image if you don't understand it. Or, you can even ask a new question and open it up to the floor.

Hello Andy,Yes it worked perfecty as shown below,but my pulse source  74ABT04 is not an idial voltage source as shown in the simulation.Where can i see in the datasheet how to model the source ?
https://ibb.co/Y0Y5q3V
https://www.mouser.co.il/datasheet/2/916/74ABT04-1541721.pdf

That I'm afraid you must ask as a new question. We've gone above and beyond with this question @rocko445
